# How do I extract the voice channel of message author in discord.py slash commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to extract the voice channel of the user and make the discord bot join their channel. I know this has been done before using normal discord commands, but I am using slash commands and they came out with it only a few months ago therefore there are not many solutions out there. This is my code

```py
@slash.slash(name='join', guild_ids=guild_ids, description='Tells the bot to join the voice channel')
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

and it outputs:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'author'
```

I have a feeling that since slash commands have a feature where the message is not actually sent as an object its hindering my code. Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `Context.author`

```py
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Yes i will, one the timer for accepting goes away